# How to round down in a forloop when using .loc in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, for-loop, numpy-slicing

I am trying to turn a float into an integer by rounding down to the nearest whole number. Normally, I use numpy's .apply(np.floor) on data in a dataframe and it works. However in this instance I am iterating in a forloop with this code:

```
f1.loc[today,'QuantityRounded'] = f1.loc[today,'QuantityNotRounded'].apply(np.floor)
```

And I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

It seems when using a forloop and .loc the numpy function doesn't work.

What is the easiest way to round down in a forloop using .loc (sorry my vocabulary here is lacking)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, just use `np.floor` directly:

```
np.floor(f1.loc[today,'QuantityNotRounded'])
```

Comment: The first suggestion works, thanks for sharing